# How to set up Codeblocks to work with mingw64

Tags: codeblocks, mingw-w64

I installed Mingw64. 
Then I set up Codeblocks by updating the toolchains executables fields in Settings/compiler. 
I was able to run a "Hello world" program.
In the task Monitor the exe is marked "*32"
So it seems it's compiled in x32

Comment: Whats your question?

Answer (score 0):

(Inferred question: Using MinGW-64, expect to get 64-bit, got 32-bit)

It depends on what MingW-w64 toolchain you have.

You must **either** add `-m64` to the commandline if you have a multilib toolchain, **or** you need to download a different one which says "targetting Win64" in its name. That is, anything that is found [in here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/). You need to choose what threading and exceptions and such you want. Or, just use the installer.

There are about a dozen different combinations that you can download from the MinGW-w64 site. You need "hosted on Windows, targets Windows", and then either the 64-bit flavor if that is all you want, or the "multi" one, but in this case you need the extra commandline switch.

X32 does not exist under Windows, it's either Win-32 or Win-64.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install Mingw64 from Msys2 then just change the compiler settings of Codeblocks so that it points to the Mingw64 folder.
Just copy and paste Mingw64 releases doesn't work in most of the time.